# How to create a custom select component that works seamlessly with Formik?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, formik

I have created a customized "Select" component in React using TypeScript and Tailwind CSS, but I am encountering issues integrating it with the Formik library for form validation. Despite my efforts, the selected option is not updating. How can I troubleshoot and fix this issue?

```
"use client"
import {FC, useState} from 'react';

interface SelectOption {
    value: string;
    label: string;
}

interface SelectProps {
    label: string;
    options: SelectOption[];
    value?: string;
    onChange: (value: string) => void;
    className?: string;
}

const Select: FC<SelectProps> = ({ label, options, value, onChange, className }) => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleOptionClick = (optionValue: string) => {
        setIsOpen(false);
        onChange(optionValue);
    };

    const selectedOption = options.find((option) => option.value === value);

    return (
        <div className={"relative text-left cursor-pointer " + className}>
            <label
                className={`${
                    selectedOption?.value ? 'text-sm left-4 -top-3 px-1 bg-white z-10' : 'text-base top-2/4 transform -translate-y-2/4'
                } 
                ${isOpen ? 'text-cyan-500' : ''}
                left-4 absolute pointer-events-none transition-all duration-200`}
                htmlFor="select"
            >
                {label}
            </label>
            <div className="relative">
                <div
                    className={`border-2 rounded-lg w-full h-14 px-4 py-4 focus:border-red-400 ${
                        isOpen ? 'border-cyan-500' : ''
                    }`}
                    onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}
                >
                    {selectedOption?.label}
                </div>
                {isOpen && (
                    <div className="absolute top-full left-0 right-0 border rounded-md bg-white shadow-lg select-none z-10">
                        {options.map((option) => (
                            <div
                                key={option.value}
                                className={`p-2 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-100`}
                                onClick={() => handleOptionClick(option.value)}
                            >
                                {option.label}
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Select;
```

There are a few more fields in the registration form, but I have removed them for convenience.

```
"use client"
import {Button, FloatingInput, ProgressBar, Radio, Select} from "../../ui";
import {useState} from "react";
import {useFormik} from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const SignUpForm = () => {
    const countryOptions = [
        {
            value: "US",
            label: "United States"
        }, {
            value: "CA",
            label: "Canada"
        }, {
            value: "FR",
            label: "France"
        }, {
            value: "DE",
            label: "Germany"
        }
    ]

    const formikAddress = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            country: 'US',
        },
        validationSchema: Yup.object({
            country: Yup
                .mixed()
                .oneOf(['US', 'CA', 'FR', 'DE'])
                .required('Country is required'),
        }),
        onSubmit: async (values) => {
            console.log(values)
        }
    });

    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={formikAddress.handleSubmit} className={"space-y-6"}>
                <Select
                    label="Country: *"
                    options={countryOptions}
                    value={formikAddress.values.country}
                    onChange={formikAddress.handleChange}
                />
                <Button type={"submit"} className={"w-full"}>Weiter</Button>
            </form>
        </>
    );
};

export default SignUpForm;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const handleOptionClick = (optionValue: string) => {
    setIsOpen(false);
    onChange(optionValue);
};
```

The issue is that you are passing a string value to `handleChange` which takes in a `ChangeEvent`.

A solution could be to bind the `value` and `handleChange` to a hidden input and handle the shown value via an internal state in the input's `onChange` event handler

**EDIT:**

Otherwise you can pass `setFieldValue` instead of `handleChange`

```
const handleOptionClick = (optionValue: string) => {
    setIsOpen(false);
    // get fieldName from props
    setFieldValue(fieldName, optionValue);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `<Field/>` formik component:

```
<Formik initialValues={{option: ""}}>
  {({ error, touched }) => (
    <Form>
      <Field name="option" >
        {({ field }) => (
          <Select
            { ...field }
            color={error.option && touched.option ? "failure" : ""}
          >
            <option value={"option 1"}>Option 1</option>
            <option value={"option 2"}>Option 2</option>
          </Select>
        )}
      </Field>
    </Form>
  )}
</Formik>
```

I had the same issue like you, I was using **flowbite** `<Select/>` component which caused the same problem for me.

You can read more about `<Field/>` in the documentation https://formik.org/docs/api/field